# Counter 3 times the same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, count

Hey guys I have a loop counter that I need the first number to repeat three times like this 1, 1, 1 and next number 2, 2, 2.

I'm only getting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
var i = 0;
function count()
{
    return i++;
}
```

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the integer part of the counter divided by 3.

```js
function count() {
    return Math.floor(i++ / 3) ;
}

var i = 3, j;

for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    console.log(count());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```